# what are the processors that support the ubuntu system

Tags: server, .desktop

Which and how many processors are supported in ubuntu?

`Example (4 Intel 32-bit processors, 16 processors PowerPC)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SupportedArchitectures

Basically, Ubuntu supports most of Intel-based processors, which are sometimes refereed to as i386 architecture, and amd64 - the 64 bit capable processors (http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.10/)

There's also Ubuntu for ARM (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/arm)